# jquery post and django response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using jquery post for pagination.
django receives the post request and issues a response.

the problem is I don't see the response being displayed in the browser.

this is the js I'm using:

```
        $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/company/sort/",
         data: {
                'type': type,
                'page': page
         },
    });
```

How can make the response from django to be displayed?

Comment: can you copy your `views.py` here ?

Comment: I'm using render_to_response to show the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add ''onsucess'' function to the structure, function that will handle response from Django.

```
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

You must add to the dictionary argument of `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/company/sort/",
    data: {
            'type': type,
            'page': page
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**Update**

If you get as an answer from the script not URL but new content of the page, you can load it to the current page using

```
$('body').replaceWith(data);
```

or

```
$('body').html(data);
```

Comment: I've tried this:
            success: function(response){
                window.location.href = response;
            }
no luck.

Comment: you send url of the page to be loaded in the answer? can you try it with `alert` to see the result?

Comment: I'm getting the right response.
but how can I redirect to it?

Comment: `window.location.href = response;` is correct. Can you please add alert before to be sure that response contains correct value and the function is executed?

Comment: I'm getting the correct result, the problem is that Django url conf can't find the url.
I need to tell jquery not to wait for response and just use the regular django functionality of render_to_response

Comment: What happens when you open this url direct in browser?

Comment: What do you mean "not to wait"? jquery doesn't wait. it just loads url that you've sent

Comment: I was trying to mimic aspt.net __doPostBack functionality.
I want to paginate using POST instead of just passing the arguments embedded in the url.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using django to render a response using templates instead of plain html.
now i need to find a way out of it.

Comment: That is not a problem. Use: ```$('body').replaceWith(data);``` or ```$('body').html(data);```

Comment: 10x, this was the correct answer!
please add it to your initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Contains some good examples.

I personally prefer:

```
$.post('url', {'data':'data'}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

You may also need to form your response from django. Here is a snippet I often use:

```
import json

def json_response(result, data):
    response = json.dumps({"result" : result, "data" : data })
    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")

def my_view(request):
    json_response(True, 'Right away Michael')
```

Comment: Should I use HttpResponse with post and not render_to_response?

Comment: There is no win with render_to_response if you are respondning with ajax. render_to_response is best used with templates. Your ajax response should be a pure http response.

Comment: I don't want to change the working functionality I have with templates.
Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: Creating ajax responses with render_to_template would be a bad idea. I don't see how my suggestion would change the working functionality. You create a view that you call from javascript.

Comment: I agree. 
but how I can dump the html from template to json?